# Flexslider carousel = Images appear to be cut off during animation/ css *Issue

Tags: html, css

Images appear to be cut off when the flexslider carousel animation starts.
Can it possible that this problem comes within the flexslider.css style code?

Full code with animation can be found here:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDRKZ/1/)

I'm putting here a partial code of the flexslider.css where the problem is suspected to be.

```
.flexslider {
  width: 250px;
  height: 600px;
  background: black;

}

.slides {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  padding-left:30px;
}
.slide {
  width: 100%;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
}


.col{
   float:right;

}
#side{
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your question reads like a recommendation question which is not within scope for StackOverflow. Read more here about questions you should avoid: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Please help!!! I'm so stuck right now and been since yesterday...

Comment: You need to post some code or an example. It tough to help abstractly with a description alone.

Comment: one moment going to put it all the codes in fiddle

Comment: This appears to render, alright (except the images of course): http://jsfiddle.net/96XLt/10/ What's the issue?

Comment: The issue is that on the web page I'm making the images appear to be cut off on the right corner and at the other side appears the cut section, something is blocking the images from being positioned complete

Comment: Post your site if you can't replicate it in fiddle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44963/discussion-between-jsuar-and-dalia)

Comment: sorry for disturbing really really sorry, ive check on chrome, and mozilla but on Internet Explorer 8 the flexslider still has the same issue is there a extra code to put for internet explorer?
for the .flexslider .slides > li { padding-left: 0; } i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to replicate your issue here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akjzx

Now, I'm not sure what's causing the issue since you couldn't get a live demo together. I recommend playing with the following CSS value. It should provide a solution to your problem.

```
.slides {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: -30px; /* Adjust this value; try a negative value */
}
```

I also recommend right-clicking the images in Chrome and selecting "Inspect element." This will help you debug the CSS and possibly determine what is causing the image to off.

Specially, you could add:

```
.flexslider .slides > li { padding-left: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm sorry to get you involved with this, but I honestly appreciate all the help, I will look into it now and  will let you know, in the worst case I'll post the website but can it be private?  Somehow I don't feel confortable posting it here.

Comment: @Dalia After a day passes you'll have to manually award the bounty since you accepted this answer before you applied the bounty. See: [How is a bounty awarded?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) "Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer."

Comment: I tried it says '' you may award your bounty in 22 hours '' :( so i guess I'll have to wait.. puff didnt know it's this complicated

Comment: Thank you for the bounty; I appreciate it. For future reference, you can award a bounty to an answer directly. No need to reassign a bounty to the question. See: [Can I award a bounty to an old answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)